# Dimension reduction (matrix) using eigenvalues and eigenvectors. PCA?

Tags: pca, matlab, matrix

I am stuck with one task where I need to reduce dimensions of the matrix 20000 by 10, compute eigenvectors and eigenvalues and determine how much the dimension can be reduced and transform the data.

I have calculated the covariance matrix (10 by 10) but stuck where to move next.
I'm working in Matlab but any advice is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: If you are working in Matlab, you can use the builtin function pca https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html It does the pca for you, and returns `coeff` (eigenvectors) and `latent` (eigenvalues). It also returns PC-scores `scores` if you need to perform dimension reduction.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any dimension reduction algorithm at all. Because the number of the dimension is 10 and it is not that much. Indeed, you need some sampling algorithms base on the nature of the data (in general case a uniform sampling).

Anyhow, if you want to do that, you need to find eigenvectors of the covariance matrix, and then project all 20000 data into the eigenvectors space (using dot product along each eigenvector). Also, you can select top eigenvectors that cover more than 95% of information (for example, it depends on what you want). Also, data normalization could be part of the task before finding eigenvectors.

Comment: thank you! That's true, but that is the task.

Comment: Thank you! What I cant find is how based on eigenvectors and eigenvalues to reduce dimensions.  Basically, eigenvalues tell the importance of eigenvectors so di I choose the most important one and create a new matrix? But based on what.. Very confusing, sorry!